# Wrong app_name shown in the list of apps

Tags: android

I defined the name of the app to be "MyApp" in strings andreferenced the app name in the manifest file to that string:

strings.xml:

```
...
<string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
....
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

However when i now install the app on my device the Application Browser
shows my app under the name "Login" which is actually the title of my 
MainActivity:

```
<activity
        android:name="de.my_project.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

strings.xml:

```
...
<string name="title_activity_login">Login</string>
...
```

When i go into my settings to deinstall the app the correct name "MyApp" is shown. Why android is showing the wrong name for my application in the application browser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each application can have several activities that handle the intent action MAIN and category LAUNCHER. Each activity means an entry point into the application. Since it is possible to create different entry points, it is possible to create different names for those entry points. By defining `android:label` in the activity, you are setting the name of the app in the application's menu.

```
<activity
    android:name="de.my_project.activities.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

LoginActivity, in this code snippet overrides the application label and uses `@string/title_activity_login`.

Remove the label from the Manifest and it should work fine. Otherwise use `@string/app_name`.

```
<activity
    android:name="de.my_project.activities.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can easily set the `title` of the activity from inside the activity.

Comment: Thx. Its the correct answer. Even if that means that i cant name my LoginActivity "Login"....

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set the name of your application in the android application browser you should set inside application tag and not activity.

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```